# Template cache in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, caching, ionic-framework, angular-templatecache

i used ionic framework to build a mobile version of my website (not a compiled add, but a webapp). The problem is that the framework loads (and maybe caches) all html templates in the first request. I'd like to disable it.
I used

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

and, for each state in stateProvider:

```
url: "/xxx",
cache: false,
```

but it resolves nothing. When i reset cache in the browser, the first request load all templates.
How is it possible? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use cache-view="false" in ion-content tag